# Is it more "pythonic" to use str() instead of ""?

Tags: python

As most Python users know, there are two ways of creating x as an empty string or list (or, for integers, 0). You could do:

```
x = str()
y = list()
z = int()
```

or, you could do:

```
x = ""
y = []
z = 0
```

I know that these are semantically identical statements, but is one more encouraged than the other (as `map()` is encouraged in some cases over `for x in y...`)?

Comment: *"as map() is encouraged in most cases over for x in y"* it's not

Comment: @vaultah Isn't it? I could have sworn it was. There's even a question on it in here somewhere... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975250/when-should-i-use-a-map-instead-of-a-for-loop

Comment: @vaultah Ah, never mind. This answer here seems to tell us that the jury is still up... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more common and more pythonic to do

```
x = ""
y = []
z = 0
```

It is more explicit, because you don't expect the reader to know what is the default value for a type.

Comment: I would tend to agree with this answer, but for a different reason: those were originally functions meant to change the type of a variable (ie, you can apply `int()` or `list()` to a string).

Answer (score 2):

I like to live by the mantra "say what you mean".  If you want an empty string, use `""`.  If you want `0`, use `0`.

The function form is useful for getting an empty value of an arbitrary builtin:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

As a **side** benefit, when you use literals it is also marginally faster since python doesn't need to look up `int`, `str`, `list` which could be shadowed.

---

It is worth pointing out that there are [famous pythonistas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745292/748858) who would disagree with me.

Comment: wow, never knew about the `defaultdict()` bit. I wonder what happens if you use it on itself...

Comment: @KnightOfNi: It will become a two-dimensional defaultdict: `defaultdict(defaultdict)`. But if you try to lookup a non-existing key `d[missing][key]`, you'll end up with a KeyError. Assignments do work however, e.g. `d[new][key] = 1337`.
BTW: Such an arbitrary builtin is officially called *default factory*

Comment: @KnightOfNi -- defaultdict can't be used on itself since the default_factory gets passed 0 arguments.  You could do:  `factory = lambda: defaultdict(factory)` and then `d = defaultdict(factory)` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`str([object])` returns a printable representation of an object.

`list([iterable])` returns a list based off of iterable

`int([object])` converts a string or number to integer.

Each of these functions return a default value if no parameter is passed. I'm not sure why you'd use these functions instead of `""`, `[]` and `0`.

Comment: I would tend to agree, see my comment on @Bartosz 's answer.

Comment: there are great pythonistas who disagree with us for container types at least:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745292/748858

Comment: Style preferences. I can respect that :)