# When/why to use map/reduce over for loops

Tags: javascript

So I am getting into a bit of object manipulation in JavaScript for the first time and I have a question I'm wondering if anyone could answer.

When I have an object I want to manipulate I could do something to the extent of a few nested for loops, however there are functions built into JavaScript, like map/reduce/filter, and libraries like lodash/underscore.

I assume the latter (map/reduce/filter and the libraries) are better practice but I'm just curious as to why.

I am doing some pretty basic object manipulation that could be solved with a few well placed for loops to grab and change the right keys/values in the object,  but can be easily done with the functions/libraries in JS. Just curious as to how they are better - like better performance/cleaner code/ease of use/whatever else.

Apologies, there is no code. I would very much appreciate anyone helping me understand more here.

Edit - so taking from the examples for map()

I could take the example for javascript.map

```
 var kvArray = [{key:1, value:10}, {key:2, value:20}, {key:3, value: 30}];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj){ 
var rObj = {};
rObj[obj.key] = obj.value;
return rObj;
});
```

I could do something like

```
   var kvArray = [{key:1, value:10}, {key:2, value:20}, {key:3, value: 30}];
var reformattedArray = [];

for(var object in kvArray){
  //combine both values into object inside of kvArray[object]);
 };
```

A lot less code - but any other benefits worth knowing about?

Comment: @suish no need to be rude. I'm curious as to this answer myself.

Comment: Cool - I didn't even know about these functions. I had to search about it after seeing your title. Then, I came upon this - it seems like a really good read regarding your topic: [From Map/Reduce to JavaScript Functional Programming](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/01/from-mapreduce-to-javascript-functional-programming/)

Comment: Map produces a new array.  Reduce accumulates some sort of single value or object.  You use them instead of a for loop or .for each if they provide the kind of output you need.  All are specialized iterators designed for certain types of output.  A for loop is a superset of the others.  More general purpose, but requires a little more typing for some things.

Comment: @jfriend00 so benefits are less code for one, but are the functions more optimized for performance than if I was to iterate through a bunch of for loops? thanks!

Comment: @ajmajmajma because it's all depends on what he wants.maybe using `map` is the best for his case,maybe underscore `_.some` is  or maybe `filter`... who could you answer the best practice for any cases? there is no perfect method which works as the best for everything.

Comment: Your both examples in lodash: `_(kvArray).map(i => [i.key, i.value]).zipObject()` <--- that's why you would like to use it instead.

Comment: I think it's show intent better.  In the end for each can do what map and reduce can do but you have to try harder to figure it out by looking at the code inside the loop.  It's shorter as well.  So if I know my intend to map or reduce, I'd rather use that since it's more terse and show exactly what my meaning for that piece of code is and they are chainable too so... map reduce ftw.

Comment: @suish See - that is a great response and would let the user know what to change in a constructive manner :).

Comment: The few times I've tested performance of `.foreach()` vs. a plain `for` loop, the `for` loop has won out each time.  I have not tested `.map()` or `.reduce()`, but would be surprised if not similar.  The likely issue is that all the helper functions have to call a function callback for each iteration of the loop which is some additional overhead, but a `for` loop does not require that overhead.  If you really wanted to know, you should run a jsperf benchmark in several browsers with your specific situation.

Comment: ...cont'd from previous comment - Any performance difference is usually not going to be meaningful so you should use whatever makes the code the cleanest.  A `for` loop also has the advantage of being able to stop the loop at any time and it works on array-like structures (such as an HTMLCollection) that are not actually arrays.

Answer (score 35):

I know I'm replying to an old answer but just wanted to point out for future readers.

Map reduce and filter functions come from the functional programming world.

These are first class built-in operators in languages like Lisp, Haskell, and others(ml?).
Functional languages tend to prefer to run operators over immutable data than make the code run over the data to operate on it (say loops).
So they provide simpler but powerful interfaces like map, filter and reduce when compared to providing for and while loops.

It also helps them satisfy other requirements like immutability etc. That's why maps give u back a new map instead of mutating the old one. These are very good from a concurrency point of view, though they may be slower in certain contexts.

This approach usually leads to fewer errors in code in multi-threaded or high concurrency apps.
When multiple actors act on the same piece of data, immutability helps keep code from stepping on each other's toes.

Since javascript tries to be partially functional by providing some functionalities of functional programming languages, it might have made sense to implement map, filter and reduce functions in it too.

YMMV depending on what you are doing with the tools you are given.

If your code works better with a for loop, go for it.

But if you ever find asynchronous code munching on common data and you end up splitting your hairs trying to debug a loop. 
Say hi, to map, reduce and filter.

Comment: I abused this...[Artistic License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license). 
Please Ignore if you are that pedantic.

Comment: Thanks for getting to the root of the matter: immutability. It isn't always about which code runs faster or looks prettier.

Comment: It also avoid strange errors when there is a global variable somewhere in the file.

Answer (score 15):

`.map()` allows you to create a new array by iterating over the original array and allowing you to run some sort of custom conversion function.  The output from `.map()` is a new array.

```
var orig = [1,2,3,4,5];
var squares = orig.map(function(val) {
    return val * val;
});
console.log(squares);   // [1,4,9,16,25]
```

---

`.reduce()` allows you to iterate over an array accumulating a single result or object.

```
var orig = [1,2,3,4,5];
var sum = orig.reduce(function(cum, val) {
    return cum + val;
}, 0);
console.log(sum);    // 15
```

These are specialized iterators.  You can use them when this type of output is exactly what you want.  They are less flexible than a `for` loop (for example, you can't stop the iteration in the middle like you can with a `for` loop), but they are less typing for specific types of operations and for people that know them, they are likely a little easier to see the code's intent.

I have not myself tested the performance of `.map()` and `.reduce()` versus a `for` loop, but have seen tests for `.forEach()` which showed that `.forEach()` was actually slower in some browsers.  This is perhaps because each iteration of the loop with `.forEach()` has to call your callback function, whereas in a plain `for` loop, you do not have to make such a function call (the code can be directly embedded there).  In any case, it is rare that this type of performance difference is actually meaningful and you should generally use whichever construct makes clearer, easier to maintain code.

If you really wanted to optimize performance, you would have to write your own test case in a tool like jsperf and then run it in multiple browsers to see which way of doing things was best for your particular situation.

---

Another advantage of a plain `for` loop is that it can be used with array-like objects that support indexing, but do not support `.reduce()` and `.map()`.

And, a `for/of` loop can be used with any object that implements the iterator protocol such as HTMLCollection.

Comment: The paragraph about performance is extra-controversial: JS engines are complex toys today and technically a `for` loop might be optimized 100x times better, just because its body is in the same function scope. Reference (in russian but is an **extremely** quality read, so please use google translate): http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/04/12/jsunderhood.html So saying that something is slower/faster in general is speculative (and confusing)

Comment: @zerkms - help me understand what is "extra-controversial"?

Comment: I tried to express something like: you cannot tell that some operator is faster than another in general. That's especially harmful for newbies: one should not design your code with very-specific performance optimizations in mind due to lack of experience. And when you have enough experience and of a facebook/google size - you already are confident enough to get JS engine and check what opcodes are generated (instead of using jsperf.com)

Comment: The ideal answer about performance of `for` vs `.map()`/`.forEach()` and others from my perspective would be: they are the same and their complexity is linear (proportional to the number of elements in a collection).

Comment: @zerkms - Why would you tell someone that performance is identical when it is not?  There are differences - even between two things that have linear proportionality.  If one wants to know those differences, one has to measure - that is always the case with performance questions.  My answer already says that this level of performance difference is rarely meaningful and the choice of which style to use should usually be made based on what makes the clearer and easier to maintain code.

Comment: "Why would you tell someone that performance is identical when it is not" --- okay. `s/the same/it does not matter/` ".forEach() was actually slower" --- the thing is that there might be a case when a callback is optimized by engine, whereas **exactly the same code** being placed as a `for` body - cannot be. That's why it's harmful (and misleading).

Comment: @zerkms -  I reported the results of a test I saw.  I did not say it's the same in all browsers and will never change.  Further, I did not say that `.map()` or `.reduce()` would perform the same, though I said I would not be surprised if they worked similarly.  You seem to be confusing what a JS engine could do vs. what the actual measured performance of the majority of JS engines actually is.  If you care to show how `.forEach()` is faster than a `for` loop, please share.

Comment: "If you care to show how .forEach() is faster than a for loop, please share." --- I don't have a particular example, I only operate with what V8 engineers say. That chat is not constructive though, sorry, I'm off. For me what you said about performance is more harmful than useful.

Comment: @zerkms - I can only go by test results I see.  I wouldn't doubt that it might be possible to make `.forEach()` as fast or faster than a `for` loop, but that theory is different than what V8 actually does in Chrome right now.  Firefox seems like it might actually do what you're talking about.

Comment: @jfriend00
 here's article on performance test for map, reduce and for loops. The for loops has the best time efficiency tor run, but there are other factors map and reduce are preferred over for loops. This article should be a nice read,
https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7

Answer (score 8):

This is like asking if I like basketball or football better.  Both have their positives.

If you have 10 developers look at your for loop, 9 out of 10 will know what you are doing right away.  Maybe half will have to look up what the `map()` method is, but then they'll also know what's going on.  So in this respect, a for loop is easier for others to read.

On the flip side, `map()` will save you two or three lines of code.

As far as performance goes, you'll find `map()` is built internally with something akin to a for loop.  You might see a few milliseconds of difference when it comes to performance speeds if you run them through large iterations; but they'll never be recognizable to an end user.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just curious because it seems most use these functions or  libraries, I was wondering if there was some dire reason to/not to use them. Thanks!

Comment: "So in this respect, a for loop is easier for others to read." --- if you don't teach your juniors - you will always use ancient techniques because "otherwise it's hard for them"

Comment: I hardly think a for loop should be dismissed as an "ancient technique", especially since it's generally many times faster than the specialized iterators.  And map and reduce have been around for a looong time, they're only new in javascript.  So age has nothing to do with it.  Consider yourself taught :-)

Comment: `You might see a few milliseconds of difference when it comes to performance speeds`. A few milliseconds by a few thousand or million items adds up pretty fast. In my own tests (when deciding on .map vs for) I found that iterating over large sets of data would take nearly an order of magnitude longer using map. For consistencies sake, I write for loops everywhere else. This is also advantageous, as developers from other languages can jump right in and know what is going on.

Comment: `map` is superior because it separates the data-structure from the business logic, making it easier to validate and refactor either/both. Any other data structure you use should also implement a `map` function. This will allow you can evolve your data-structure and business logic independently.

Answer (score 5):

**forEach()**: Executes a provided function(callback) once for each array element. Doesn’t return anything (*undefined*) but this callback is allowed to mutate the calling array.

**map()**: Executes a provided function(callback) once for each array element and creates a new array with the results of this execution. It cannot mutate the calling array content.

**Conclusion**

Use `map()` when you need to return a new array.

Use `forEach()` when you want to change the original array

Use `for` when you need more control over the iteration (eg: you want to iterate every three elements (`i + 3`))

Comment: `forEach` is definitely not the same thing as a `for` loop which this question is asking

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into this while searching for something else. So trying to answer it even if it is a old thread as the concepts applies no matter what.

If you consider performance and flexibility, "for" loop always beats the others, just because it doesn't have the overhead of calling a function for each iteration and can be used for any purpose.

But, there are other gains with functions like forEach, map, reduce etc (let's call them functional methods). It is mainly the readability, maintainability.

Below are few drawbacks of for loop

1. Introduces new variables to the scope, just for the counter/iteration
2. Hard to debug errors, due to un-intentional changes to counter variables. This becomes more difficult and the chances to make a mistake increases more as the number of loops with in loops increase
3. Developers have the habit of using loop variables as i, j, k. It is very easy to lose the track of which counter and which inner loop the code is executing once the loop increases certain lines of code
4. With ES6, we have at least limited/local scope introduced by 'let'. But before, the variables introduced by for loop have a function scope causing even more accidental errors

To avoid all of these, it is suggested to use functions like forEach, map, reduce when you know what you have to do (Not to forget most of these functional methods offer immutability). A small sacrifice in terms of performance for the greater good and more succinct code.

With ES6, most of the functional methods are supported by the language itself. They are optimised and we don't have to rely on libraries like lodash (unless there is a severe performance gain).

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into this and found that none of the answers highlights one important difference between `for-loop` and `map` as to when to use one over the other:

1. With `map` you can't break out of an iteration which you can with `for-loop`.

For e.g, you can't do this

```
const arr = [5, 6, 9, 4];
arr.map(elem=>{
   if(elem === 5){
     break; //This is not allowed
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarising the differences between higher-order array methods (`map`, `reduce`, `filter`, etc. - I'll refer to these as **HOMs**) vs `for` loops, and including a few other points:

- Counter variables: `for` loops introduce variables that introduce errors such as: [OBOE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjXwJbc9ufxAhWfgf0HHePFCloQFnoECAgQAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FOff-by-one_error&usg=AOvVaw06ia8NC_XBrWOZnyzHe9w1); block scoping errors (which are complicated further by the differences in `let` and `var` declaration scoping)
- Availability: HOMs are only available to objects that are arrays (`Array.isArray(obj)`); `for` loops can be used on objects that implement the iterator protocol (which includes arrays),
- Early execution exit: there is none for HOMs; loops have the `break` and `return` statement for this,
- Consecutive `async` iteration execution: Not possible in HOMs. Notice that only a loop can delay between console logging executions:

```
// Delays for a number of milliseconds
const delay = (ms = 1000) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const printItem = async (item) => {
  await delay();
  console.log(item);
}

const testForLoopParallelism = async () => {
  for (const item of items) {
    await printItem(item);
  }
};
const testHigherOrderParallelism = () => {
  return Promise.all(items.map(async item => await printItem(item)));
}

const run = async () => {
  // Prints consecutively at a rate of ~1s, for a total of ~3s
  console.time('for');
  await testForLoopParallelism();
  console.timeEnd('for');

  // Prints all concurrently, for a total of ~1s
  console.time('HOM');
  await testHigherOrderParallelism();
  console.timeEnd('HOM');
};

run();
```

Less importantly but worth noting:

- Verbosity: array HOMs may be shorter than `for` loops
- Subjectively easier to read: this can be argued for both HOMs and for `for ... in` loops
- Subjectively better understood: loops may be more well known than HOMs for Javascript newcomers
- Performance: May have performance differences that may need to be considered in high performance codebases on a case-by-case basis
- Immutability aid: May aid in providing immutability - although it is possible to create mutations using either HOMs or `for` loops, e.g.,

```
items.map((item) => {
  items.push(item);
  return `${item}x`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`map`, `reduce`, etc are functions that container-like data-structures should implement so that consumers can make use of them without having to understand their internals. These functions accept your logic as input. This allows you to implement changes to the internals of those data-structures without affecting their consumers.

The real reason why `map` is superior to `for` loops is because they are much easier to develop with as your application evolves. What if your requirements change such that you now have an object?

```
import map from 'lodash/fp/map';
import mapValues from 'lodash/fp/mapValues';

const before = map(logic, data);
const after = mapValues(logic, data);
```

And again, what if your requirements change such that now you have a tree? Well, now you're a good developer that realises that the code that is responsible for traversing the tree should be separated from the business logic. It should be written once, thoroughly tested once, be maintained by the team that owns the data-structure, and accept business logic as input. All so that consumers do not have to worry about its internals.

Instead, consumers should just do this.

```
import { mapTreeValues } from 'tree'

const before = map(logic, data);
const after = mapTreeValues(logic, data);
```

Long story short, `for` should only ever be used by owners of data structures to implement functions such as `map`, `reduce`, etc. These functions should never be coupled to business logic, instead they should accept it as input. Remember the single responsibility principle?

Aside: To preempt comparison with custom iterables, there are benefits to these being higher-order functions to improve ease of composition. For example:

```
getUser().then(updateUser)
getUsers().then(map(updateUser))
```