# `for` loops vs `.map` to iterate arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a specific reason why is better to use `.map` than `for` loops in React?

I'm working on a project where all arrays are being iterated with `for` loops but I'm convinced that is better and good practice to use `.map` because it creates a copy of the array, that to my understanding is better practice but I can't find a specific reason.

Comment: `.map` is good for conciseness and readability. `for` loops are still an option, they're just not a nice-looking one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When/why to use map/reduce over for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640254/when-why-to-use-map-reduce-over-for-loops)

Comment: For these kinds of good practices, I have written an article. You can read it. JavaScript best Practices.

https://medium.com/swlh/how-not-to-write-code-javascript-62a7fa1f819c

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a specific reason why is better to use .map than for loops in React?

If you're just *iterating*, `map` is the wrong tool. `map` is for *mapping* arrays: producing a *new* array based on the values from the previous array. Someone somewhere is teaching `map` as an iteration tool, unfortunately, doing their students a disservice. (I wish I knew who it was so I could have a word.) Never do this:

```
// Don't do this
myArray.map(entry => {
    // ...do something with `entry`...
});
```

For *iteration*, it's a choice between a `for` loop, a `for-of` loop, and the `forEach` method. (Well, and a few other things; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for a thorough rundown.)

For instance, using `forEach`

```
myArray.forEach(entry => {
    // ...do something with `entry`...
});
```

vs. using `for-of`:

```
for (const entry of myArray) {
    // ...do something with `entry`...
}
```

(Those aren't quite equivalent. The former has to be an array. The latter can be any iterable object.)

The reason you may see `map` a lot in React is that you're frequently mapping things in React, in at least two ways:

1. Mapping from raw data to JSX elements, like this:

   ```
   return (
       <div>
       {myData.map(({id, name}) => <div key={id}>{name}</div>)}
       </div>
   );
   ```

   Since that's a mapping operation, with the array created by `map` being used to provide the contents of the outer `div`, `map` is the right choice there.
2. Mapping from old state to new state, like this:

   ```
   const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
   // ...
   setMyArray(myArray.map(obj => {...obj, update: "updated value"}));
   ```

   Since that again is a mapping operation, creating a new array to set as the `myArray` state member, `map` is the right choice.

> ...but I'm convinced that is better and good practice to use .map because it creates a copy of the array...

**If** you want a copy/updated version of the array, yes, `map` is a good choice. It's more concise than the equivalent `for` loop (or even `for-of`):

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(entry => /*...update...*/);
```

vs.

```
// Probably not best practice unless you have conditional logic
// in the loop body that may or may not `push` (or similar)
const newArray = [];
for (const entry of oldArray) {
    newArray.push(/*...update...*/);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.map()` maps each array value to a new value, and returns a brand new array.
 In React.js context, `.map()` can be used to map each array item to a piece of JSX fragment.

`for` loop also iterates over an array, just like `.map()`. The major difference is that you can specify custom computation with `for` loop. Whereas `.map()` is specifically designed for mapping