# knowing when to use a loop or map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, loops, for-loop

Trying to learn by coding (React), my question: React uses map() everywhere, so can we replace every loop for example for loop with map ?
When is good to use map and when for loop ? in following example i have used for loop, should i be using map ?

how would this be changed to map ?:

```js
 const links = currentLinks;
      for (let i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
        let border = links[i].boundary.points;
        drawPath(canvas, ctx, border, '#AA1111', '#AA1111', 0.2);
      }
      
      
      
      -----------------
      
      links.map(() => (
      ?
      
      ));
```

Comment: use map when you want to return something. for example in react return jsx.

Comment: always when returning ? that for loop cant be replaced with map ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60786111/for-loops-vs-map-to-iterate-arrays

Comment: The OP does not return anything with each iteration step but the OP ***for each*** iteration step, and based on the currently processed item, executes/invokes another process/function. Thus, if at all picking an array method it should be [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map =>  For Transformation or Projection - It gives a new collection

loops => For doing some operation (on the collection itself or in general) - It does not return anything

For example

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You want to get the doubles of each number in the array

```
const doubled = data.map((number, index) => number * 2);

//-- Output 

[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

You want to call some method (or perform some action) if the item is between 2 and 5

```
data.forEach(number => { 
    if(number > 2 && number < 5){
        //call some method
    }
    else{
        //..... do some other work
    }
}
```

or

```
for(let i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    const number = data[i];
    if(number > 2 && number < 5){
        //call some method
    }
    else{
        //..... do some other work
    }
}
```

I know the examples are contrived and not very good, but I hope you get the point. Let me know in the comments if you have any query

**Update**
For your case you could use map as below

```js
links.map(link => {
  let border = link.boundary.points;
  drawPath(canvas, ctx, border, '#AA1111', '#AA1111', 0.2);
});
```

Comment: @walee I did not downvted. I upvoted your question. Your question is valid. Ignore these people,

Comment: If you replace my example code with map, would it be like this : links.map((k) => drawPath( canvas, ctx, links[k]?.boundary?.points, '#AA1111', '#AA1111', 0.2, ), ); ?

Comment: @walee Sorry my mistake, map's first parameter is item and second is index. I have updated the answer again

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of preference, but in my book, using loops a lot means someone is less experienced. The main difference is that you need to keep the *state* when you're using a loop. And when you're using a *state*, you need to think of a name for it and - believe it or not - that's sometimes the hardest part. On the other hand, `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.reduce()` etc. are just expressions.

Use whatever you prefer, but use it wisely.

That being said, sometimes using a loop makes more sense. The rule of thumb is that whenever your code generates some kind of *side effect*, using a loop is more logical. Consider these two examples:

```js
for (const fruit of fruits) {
    draw(fruit);
}

// or:

fruits.forEach(
    fruit => draw(fruit) // makes sense
);

// vs.

fruits.map(
    fruit => draw(fruit)
);
```

All will work and do the same thing, but the last one is rather amateurish to do. It returns an array of whatever `draw()` returns and that return value is never used, so the purpose of using an expression is lost.

To sum up:

- expression? use `.map()`
- side effect? use loops

Comment: if you were to change that for loop into map, how would it be ?

Comment: In your case you're using a *side effect* by calling `drawPath()`, so using a loop makes sense. I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost if you know you need to break out early then you need to use a loop as you can not return early with forEach and map (without the use of something like filter).

Also specific for react you will get a re-render if state or properties change.  Using map will create a new array (at least the reference to the array) which will get you a re-render which is often desired.