# Which way of iterating array and changing element by map is more efficient?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a question about map.As you know by using map we can iterate arrays and able to change the element of arrays.To do that there are two ways and I listed them below.Which way has less complexity and more performance?(In the examples arrays are not big but think about the real world like 500 elements in an array)

```
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
numbers=numbers.map(e=>{
 return e=e*2;
})
```

In this approach assigning each returned value to current array.

```
numbers.map((e,a)=>{
  numbers[a]=e*2;
})
```

In this one on each iteration we need to go to array by index to find element and I think this is worse than above but Im not sure.

Comment: No need for a map if you do not need a new Array. Just use forEach

Comment: As I know,map has less complexity then forEach but difference is very very less

Comment: No.  map creates a new array and allows representing a chainable functional transformation.  It generally represents directly transforming object shape more elegantly.  The other way mutates the array in place.  Performance is normally negligible, but mutating in place avoids object initalization, so will outperform if the amount of data to manipulate is very very large

Comment: The "complexity" of `.map()` and `.forEach()` are basically the same, though because `.forEach()` does not create a new array it's slightly *less* "complex".

Comment: second approach will be more efficient if `forEach` is used in place of `map` it will save space whereas no impact on time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When/why to use map/reduce over for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640254/when-why-to-use-map-reduce-over-for-loops)

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `map` if you're not going to use the array it creates. If you just want to loop through an array, use a loop or `forEach` or similar.

Whether you want a new array or not, the *most efficient* way to loop through an array is usually a `for` loop:

```
const numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
for (let i = 0, len = numbers.length; i < len; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 2;
}
```

(Or any of several variations on that.)

**But "most efficient" is extremely unlikely to actually matter in real-world code**, so using things like `map` (if you want a new array) or `forEach` (if you don't) is just fine. `map` is idiomatic for that operation (creating a new array containing the entries from a previous array modified in some way).

Conclusion:

If you want a new array, feel free to use `map`, or create a blank array and use [any of your options for looping arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) to loop the original and add entries to the new one.

If you don't want a new array, don't use `map`, use any of your options for iterating over the original except for ones that don't give you the index, and assign the updated value back to the entry.

Answer (score 2):

Semantically you need `for` or `forEach` when you do not need a new array.
For sufficiently small arrays there is no difference in performance

```js
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];
numbers.forEach((e,i)=> numbers[i] = e*2);
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: _"...I dislike..."_ - That's an opinion and not an answer.

Comment: @Andreas it is both an answer AND something I strongly agree on. I changed my semantics to not trigger you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
nums.forEach((v, i) => nums[i] = v);
```

is the fastest method possible that you listed (equivalent to your second method. Why? `nums = nums.map(...)` creates an entire **copy** of the array in memory and replaces the array with that copy. When you simply iterate over the array with an index and replace elements, you avoid making that copy, and it ends up being around 15% faster (see [this benchmark](https://jsbench.me/l9katoihet/1).

Comment: [Which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: *"...is the fastest method possible..."* No, a `for` loop is, since it avoids all those function calls. It's just extremely unlikely to matter, because function calls are *really really fast*. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to change a value of an array is to iterate the index and update the item.

This approach is faset than `forEach` or `map`, because it does not have the overhead of `this` and it does not need the feature of the supplied structure of the callback.

```js
var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) numbers[i] *= 2;

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: So you think that for loop has less complexity than forEach?

Comment: Then why forEach is more popular if its not as powerful as for loop?

Comment: it depends on the use.

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek - One of the reasons `forEach` *used* to be so popular was that it gave you a contained scope for variables in the "body" of the "loop" back before JavaScript had block scope. Now that JavaScript has block scope and the `for-of` loop, you see `forEach` a **lot** less...