# What's the best way to figure out 'undefined' in several variables?

Tags: javascript

When there are several variables and figure out even one of them is `undefined`, which code is the best one?

variable is like below

```js
const [a, b, c] = [1, '4', undefined]
```

1. use `Array.includes`

```js
[a, b, c].map(e => typeof e).includes('undefined')
```

2. use `for ... of`

```js
for (const e of [a, b, c]) {
    if (typeof e === 'undefined') {
        // 'undefined' found
    }
}
```

3. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean under "the best code".
If you care about readability, you should choose the functional way.

> even one of them is undefined

According to the description, the method you are looking for is `some`.
Also, it's better to check for undefined explicitly, preferring the `typeof` operator

```js
const array = [1, '4', undefined];

const isOneOfThemIsUndefined = array.some(e => typeof e === 'undefined'))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `includes` call will do, without the `typeof` mapping:

```
[a, b, c].includes(undefined)
```

Comment: With the *minor* caveat that this will return true for a sparse Array. Might actually even be what one would want in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const array = [1, '4', undefined];
 const isOneOfThemIsUndefined = array.filter(Boolean)

 console.log(isOneOfThemIsUndefined)

// =>  [1, '4',]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use without typeOf as `if (e === undefined)` in for loop
Now coming back to your question. As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641196/15107474) it depends on your use scenario.
If the majorly of the arrays are reasonably small then you can use either. But if they are extremely large, a for loop is preferable as it's much faster than `.map()`

Comment: Please don't capitalize every word in a sentence. It reads awful because it looks like every word is a new sentence. See https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-rules/