# Convert lists of lists of string into a list of string efficently

Tags: python, string, list

I have a lists of lists of strings which I would like to convert to a list of strings adding a space between each list item. eg.

```
original_list = [['the', 'cat', 'in', 'the', 'hat'], ['fat', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']]

desired_output = ['the cat in the hat', 'fat cat sat on the mat']
```

I understand that I can do it using this:

```
desired_output
for each in original_list:
    desired_output.append(' '.join(each))
```

but as I am working with large amounts of data am ideally looking for a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: It should be `' '.join(each)` instead of `''.join(each)` in your code

Comment: @KaushikNP Cheers - it was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.join` with a full space `' '`:

```
original_list = [['the', 'cat', 'in', 'the', 'hat'], ['fat', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']]
final_list = [' '.join(i) for i in original_list]
```

Output:

```
['the cat in the hat', 'fat cat sat on the mat']
```

Comment: Um, how is this an optimisation? The OP has already done this, just not using `list comprehension`.

Comment: @KaushikNP `str.join` is much faster than string concatenation because  strings are immutable and thus cannot be changed in place.

Comment: But that's not what the user has done. The OP too has used `join`. But yeah, one thing I overlooked. The user used `append` and `list comprehension` has a slight advantage there. So works out. +1

Comment: @KaushikNP it also optimised LOCs, reducing dev time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another pythonic and simple way, in Python 3, could be using `map`, says another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975250/when-should-i-use-a-map-instead-of-a-for-loop) discussion it should be faster, it would go like this:

```
original_list = [['the', 'cat', 'in', 'the', 'hat'], ['fat', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']]

#              (------where magic happens--------)
desired_list = list(map(' '.join, original_list ))

#print
#output ['the cat in the hat', 'fat cat sat on the mat']
```