# How to print list of strings with lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have a list of strings that print out just fine using a normal loop:

```
for x in listing:
    print(x)
```

I thought it should be pretty simple to use a lambda to reduce the loop syntax, and kickstart my learning of lambdas in Python (I'm pretty new to Python).

[Given that the syntax](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#map) for `map` is `map(function, iterable, ...)` I tried:

```
map(lambda x: print(x), listing)
```

But this does not print anything out (it also does not produce an error). I've done some searching through material online but everything I have found to date is based on Python 2, namely mentioning that with Python 2 this isn't possible but that it *should* be in Python 3, without explicitly mentioning how so.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator:

```
>>> map(print, listing)
<map object at 0x7fabf5d73588>
```

This iterator is *lazy*, which means that it won't do anything until you iterate over it. Once you *do* iterate over it, you get the values of your list printed:

```
>>> listing = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for _ in map(print, listing):
...     pass
... 
1
2
3
```

What this also means is that `map` isn't the right tool for the job. `map` creates an iterator, so it should only be used if you're planning to iterate over that iterator. It shouldn't be used for side effects, like printing values. See also [When should I use `map` instead of a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975250/when-should-i-use-a-map-instead-of-a-for-loop).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) here, as you don't really care about the iterator.  If you want to simplify the basic "for loop", you could instead use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> mylist = ['hello', 'there', 'everyone']
>>> '\n'.join(mylist)
hello
there
everyone
```

Or if you have a non-string list:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4]
>>> '\n'.join(map(str, mylist))
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks. While Aran-Fey's answer does answer the question I asked, your answer shows me how to do what I actually wanted, so both equally valid IMO :)